# Quaternionic projective space in complex Grassmannian

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, schubert-calculus

I would like to consider the quaternionic projective space $\mathbb{PH}^{n-1}\subset\mathbb{G}_2(\mathbb{C}^{2n})$ as a subvariety of the Grassmannian of complex 2-planes. 
For a real vector $e\in\mathbb{R}^{4n}$ the inclusion is just given by
$$
\mathbb{H}\cdot e
=
\mathbb{C}\cdot e
\oplus
\mathbb{C}\cdot Je.
$$
One has
$$
\mathbb{PH}^{n-1}
=
\{V\in\mathbb{G}_2(\mathbb{C}^{2n})\colon JV=V\}.
$$

My question is: "how to compute the fundamental class of
$\mathbb{PH}^{n-1}$
in
$\mathbb{G}_2(\mathbb{C}^{2n})$"?

Comment: Sounds like a fun variant of a Schubert calculus problem: how many 2-planes in a given Schubert variety are quaternionic, i.e. fixed by J?  The answer is the coefficient of your fundamental class in the Schubert basis.  For example there is a unique quaternionic line containing a given complex line, that gives a coefficient of "1" for one of the Schubert varieties.

Comment: Probably better use a flag $F$ that is transverse to $JF$, so that $HP^{n-1}$ meets the middle-dimensional Schubert varieties transversely.

Comment: For the analog question for vector bundles, is there an easy way to compute the coefficients for lower codimensional Schubert varieties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I understand David Treumann indications.

- We take a flag $F$ of $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$ such that $JF$ is the opposite flag.
- The complex codimension of $\mathbb{HP}^{n-1}$ in $\mathbb{G}_2(\mathbb{C}^{2n})$ being $2(n-1)$ (half of the dimension of the Grassmannian), we consider middle dimensional Schubert varieties $X_\lambda$, associated to partitions $\lambda$ of length $2(n-1)$ with at most two parts, i.e. of the form $(2n-1-i,i-1)$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.
- These Schubert varieties are defined by the incidence conditions
  $$\dim(V\cap F_i)\geq 1\text{ and }\dim(V\cap F_{2n+1-i})\geq 2,$$
  that is
  $$\dim(V\cap F_i)\geq 1\text{ and }\dim(V\cap JF_{i-1})=0.$$
  So $\mathbb{HP}^{n-1}$ meets each of these middle dimensional Schubert varieties transversely in one point.
- Thus in the Schubert basis $[\mathbb{HP}^{n-1}]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}[X_{2n-1-i,i-1}]$. By Giambelli formula this is
  $$[\mathbb{HP}^{n-1}]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}s_{2n-1-i,i-1}(U)=s_{n-1}(U)s_{n-1}(U),$$
  where (U) is the universal subbundle on the Grassmann bundle.