# Quaternionic projective bundle in complex Grassmann bundle

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, schubert-calculus

*"What is the fundamental class of the projective bundle of lines of a quaternionic bundle in the Grassmann bundle of 2-planes of the underlying complex bundle?"*

---

In [Quaternionic projective space in complex Grassmannian](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244180/), thanks to the help of *David Treumann*, I was able to compute the fundamental class of the quaternionic projective space in the complex Grassmannian of 2-planes.

I now would like to investigate the case of vector bundles.

---

Let $E\to X$ be a rank $n$ quaternionic vector bundle on a variety $X$, and $E_\mathbb{C}$ the underlying rank 2n complex bundle.
Then the projective bundle of lines $\mathbb{H}P(E)$ can be seen as a subvariety of the Grassmann bundle $G_2(E_\mathbb{C})$, given by
$$
\mathbb{H}P(E)
=
\{
V\in G_2(E_\mathbb{C})
\colon
JV=V
\}
$$
where $J$ on $G_2(E_\mathbb{C})$ is induced by the left multiplication by $J\in\mathbb{H}$ on $E$. The complex dimension of the fibers of $\mathbb{H}P(E)$ is half the one of $G_2(E_\mathbb{C})$, that is 2(n-1).

I want to express the fundamental class of the quaternionic bundle of lines in the Schubert basis of the Grassmann bundle. The Schubert varieties involved have codimension at most 2(n-1). The argument for vector space gives the intersection with medium dimensional Schubert varieties, which is 1, but I don't know how to compute the other coefficients.

---

*Example* If n=2, the fundamental class is
$$
[\mathbb{H}P(E)]
=
[X_{(2)}]+[X_{(1,1)}]+?[X_{(1)}]+?[X_{\emptyset}]
$$

*Question* what are the missing coefficients, in the Chow ring of the base variety?